# Entity Framework with foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

In short how is Entity Framework suppose to work with related tables.

aspnetcore 2.0

```
public class Table1{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Table2")]
    public int Table2Id {get;set;}
    public virtual Table2 Table2{get;set;}
}

public class Table2{
    [Key]
    public int Id{get;set;}

}
```

I assumed that with the statement

```
var t1 = context.Table1List.FirstOrDefault( j => j.Id == 1)
```

would have automatically populated Table2 but t1.Table2 is null.

If I was to call context.Table2List.FirstOrDe..... then t1.Table2 is populated even without setting the property.  So EF recognizes the relationship just does not populate until I physically make the call to the DB.

Is my understanding of how EF is suppose to work wrong or is just an error in my code.  Maybe something to do with lazyloading.

I have read and read and read Microsofts tutorials but with no much understanding how it is Suppose to work versus how it actually works.

Table 1 and 2 only have a one to one relationship with each other.

Comment: Your design is confusing - is `Id` supposed to be the primary key of `Table1` or the foreign key of `Table2`? Can you please the SQL definition of both tables?

Comment: You need to add an include to populated Table2: `context.Table1List.Include(t => t.Table2).FirstOrDefault( j => j.Id == 1)`

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: @aguafrommars Exactly right. the same as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

You have to change your model like:

```
public class Table1{
    public int Id{get; set;} //Primary key by convention
    [ForeignKey("Table2")]
    public int Table2Id{get; set;}
    public virtual Table2 Table2{get; set;}
}

public class Table2{
    public int Id{get; set;} //Primary key by convention
    public virtual Table1 Table1{get; set;}
}
```

And in you context you have to set this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure table1 & table2 entity
    modelBuilder.Entity<Table2>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Table1) // Mark Table1 property optional in Table2 entity
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.Table2); // mark Table1 property as required in Table2 entity. Cannot save Table1 without Table
}
```

And when you want to get data from one table, also get data from related table, you have using `Include` method in you query like:

```
var result  = var t1 = context.Table1List.Include(x=>x.Table2).FirstOrDefault( j => j.Id == 1);
```

with this code, you have data about related table.

if you want, I can create more sample for you.

Comment: Did you just copy/pasted the class definitions from @spender 's answer? Big LOL

Comment: No luck.  I have a lot of models already set up this way as well.  they dont work either.  However, I believe you are saying yes to assumption that EF is suppose to populate these automatically. Also table 1 and 2 have a 1 to 1 relationship.  So the list of table1s is not a true statement.  I believe my model shows this.  Also Table 1 and 2 share the ID.  If I was to run your code it would not find Table2Id.

Comment: @Mike Do you set your property as Virtual?

Comment: I removed the last comment... adding Include worked.  Thats all I did.  However I was under the impression that I would not have to do this.  and adding include is essentially the same as me writing another statement to fetch the table.  I dont think I have tried the "WithRequired" setting in the OnModelCreating.  this looks positive.  I will try it out too.  However your example is still wrong.  There is no column named Table2Id.  Simply Table1 and 2 share the same Id.  If I was to add the Column("...") attribute then I get a duplicate error. My example does not show virtial but my code does.

Comment: @Mike In my opinion your problem is in your table, because is not correct, please check this line http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx to know information about table generating.

Comment: I dont think the error has to do with my code or at least with my models and DB because adding Include(func) worked without error.  So this tells me its a setting that is not set correctly.  I marked our answer up because it worked.  Just not how I had intended it to.

Comment: @Mike I don’t no really, Do you test Include method?? If yes, what is you result? Do you have any error?? I think you get firstordefault, and first of you data, don’t have any data about table2

Comment: as mentioned in the two comments above.  Yes I tested the include and that worked.  This is why i marked your score up.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the wiring-up mostly to convention and assuming a 1 to many relationship, did you mean to make a set of models that looks like this?

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     // Primary key by convention
    [ForeignKey("Table2")]
    public int Table2Id { get; set; }
    public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}

public class Table2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }     //Primary key by convention
    public ICollection<Table1> Table1s { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see comment on AmirReza-Farahlagha

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called [Lazy Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading)

By checking documetation, you see that you must explicitly enable lazy loading:

```
.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

And your `Table2` property must be `virtual`:

```
public class Table1 
{  
    public virtual Table2 Table2{get;set;}
}
```

You don't even need `Id` foreign key!

Comment: I will try the Lazy loading...  I think I tried this before but dont remember why id did not work.  The example I had was a bit different from yours.  Will get back to you on that.  You will need the foreign key attribute if you dont have the exact format for the properties or set it in onModelBuilding.  Your last statement is not entirely true.

Comment: @Mike sure, check also [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property). And, as I see, you're using both `Key`. `ForeignKey` attributes, you should introduce new property for your foreign key.

Comment: No option for UseLazyLoadingProxies  is there a particular reference for this?

Comment: Note that: _This feature was introduced in EF Core 2.1._ Which version of EF Core do you have?

Comment: 2.0
AmirReza... helped by just adding Include to the context.  All worked at that point.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that's another possibility of loading related data, so called [Eager Loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading). It's up to you which possibility to use, but if you need Lazy Loading like in your question, you must have EF Core 2.1 version.